# Как сделать звонок с сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Добрый день. Встала такая задача.
На сайте размещен телефон компании. Надо сделать так, чтобы если человек просматривает сайт с мобильного телефона, он мог кликнуть на него и у него автоматически запустилась бы возможность набора выбранного номера.
Пример реализации данной функции можно увидеть [здесь](http://www.kufar.by/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_75_75_4418318.htm?first=1).
*Смотреть пример надо с мобильного.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте ссылку ввида:

```
<a href="tel:70951234567">7(095)123-45-67</a>
```

Вместо `tel:` может использоваться так же `callto:`, который понимается Skype'ом и некоторыми другими программами, но при этом не является стандартом.

Вообще, пока что, борьба между callto и tel не закончена и споры, что лучше, продолжаются.

Подробнее:

- RFC 2806
- RFC 3966
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/ (англ.)